# События javascript внутри тегов

Tags: javascript, html

Сразу прошу, не минусуйте, пжлст, так как нужен совет, касаемо объявлений событий js внутри тегов. Я слышал много мнений тех, кто за, и кто против. Одни говорят, что объявлять события внутри тегов это не очень хорошая практика, а другая сторона утверждает обратное. Все таки, какие последствия может понести за собой объявление событий в тегах?!

Типа этого:

```
<div onlick="fname()">...</div>
```

Какие плюсы и минусы? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Последствия объявления событий в тегах:

1. Скрипт в JS, а вызов функций из этого скрипта в HTML. Может быть не удобно перемещаться туда-сюда, и не подходит под идею разделения технологий. HTML должен быть для структуры документа, а не для действий.
2. В тегах можно написать только одно событие, два onClick не получится повесить на один тег. А в JS можно вешать сколько угодно одинаковых обработчиков на один элемент методом `element.addEventListener()`.
3. Написав событие в тег, вы теряете возможность использовать объект события типа Event, который даёт дополнительные возможности.
4. Написанное в теге событие вы не можете удалить посредством HTML. Получается, что при надобности будете удалять через JS. И возникает вопрос почему они не добавляются там же в JS.
5. При клонировании элементов через JS, будут клонироваться написанные в тегах события, чего не происходит при клонировании узлов с событиями, добавленными через JS.
6. Один кусок HTML можно использовать для разных задач. Например применять к нему разный скрипт или делать из него элементы множество раз. Написанные в теги события будут мешать или усложнять.

Comment: Спасибо за конкретику. То, что хотел услышать.

Answer (score 3):

В том и дело, что "много мнений тех, кто за, и кто против". Но всегда стоит смотреть на "хорошую практику". Есть определённые стандарты. Как у `PHP` его `PSR`, например.

Вообще, здесь стоит провести аналогию с `CSS`. Не стоит писать стили в инлайновом виде (внутри тегов), если можно вывести всё это в отдельный файл в отдельной директории.

То есть, `<div style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">Content</div>`.

Тоже самое и с `JavaScript`. Не стоит загрязнять код подобными вставками. Используйте селекторы по ID, классу или тегам, например. И уже из скрипта цепляйтесь с нужным элементам DOM-дерева.

Такой код самому легче поддерживать и другим. Чёткость и структурируемость кода - это признак профессионализма разработчика.

Я бы посоветовал Вам **НЕ** использовать инлайновый метод написания скриптов и стилей.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сам то я никогда не использовал этот, как вы выразились инлайновый метод (только в универе). Всегда выношу код в кастомный js, и обращаюсь к элементам методом `querySelector`. Просто интереса ради решил спросить. И на счет чёткости и структурированности кода абсолютно согласен.